# How to save API output data to a Dataset in Azure Data Factory

Tags: api, rest, post, dataset, azure-data-factory

I'm currently working on a project in Azure Data Factory, which involves collecting data from a Dataset, using this data to make API calls, and thereafter taking the output of the calls, and posting them to another dataset.
In this way I wish to end up with a dataset containing various different data, that the API call returns to me.
My current difficulty with this is, that do not know how to make the "Web activity" (which I use to make the API Call) save its output to my dataset.
I have tried numerous different solutions found online, however none of them seem to work. I am not sure if the official documentation is outdated or if I'm misunderstanding parts of it. Below I've listed links to the solutions I've tried and failed:

1. [Copy data from a REST source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest)
2. [Copy data from an HTTP source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http)
3. (among others, including similar posts to mine.)

The current flow in my pipeline is, that a "Lookup" collects a list of variables named "User_ID". These user ID's are put in to a ForEach loop, which makes an API call with the "Web" activity, using each of the USER_ID's. And this is where in the pipeline I wish to implement an activity or other, that can post each of these Web activity outputs into my new dataset.

I've tried to use the "Copy data" activity, but all it seems to do, is copying data straight from one dataset to another, and not being able to manipulate the data (which i wish to do with my api call).

Does anyone have a solution to how this is done?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you could not achieve this following [Copy data from a REST endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-rest). I tested the below which works fine. I used [schema mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping) feature of 'Copy data' activity.

For example, I used a sample API http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees as source and for my testing, I used CosmosDB as sink. Of course you can choose any other dataset as per your requirement.

1. Create 'Linked Service' for the REST API. For simplicity I do not have authentication for this API. Of course, you have that option if required.
   [image]
2. Create 'Linked Service' for the target data store. In my case, it is CosmosDB.
   [image]
3. Create Dataset for the REST API and link to the linked service created in #1.
   [image]
4. Create Dataset for the Data store (in my case CosmosDB) and link to the linked service created in #2.
   [image]
5. In the pipeline, add a 'Copy data' activity like below with source as the REST dataset created in #3 and sink as the dataset created in #4. Also, in my case I had to add schema mapping to select the employees array from the API output and map to each field in my datastore.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
6. And voila, that's it. When I run the pipeline, it calls the REST API and saves the output in my DB with my desired mapping.
   [image]